# Libgdx bullet offset origin

Tags: libgdx, bullet, bulletphysics, rigid-bodies

i am using blender to create my models, and loading them into Libgdx, if i create them with the Origin in the center of the model like below and then use this code to create the rigid body, all works fine

```
        Vector3 hescoWallHalfExtents = new Vector3(hescoWall.calculateBoundingBox(bounds).getDimensions()).scl(0.5f);
```

[image]

however if i place the bottom of the model level with the ground like this

[image]

then the btRigidbody is offset like this

[image]

is there an obvious way that i can offset the height of the rigidbody?

many thanks.

Spriggsy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The center (origin) of the rigid body is the same as the center of mass and therefor an important property for the physics simulation. You could "move" this center using a `btCompoundShape` if you like, but this will also influence the physics simulation and therefore probably won't give you satisfying results.

Alternatively, you could compensate for the difference of physics origin and visual origin in your `btMotionState`. For example by setting `ModelInstance#transform` to the provided `worldTransform` multiplied by the a `Matrix4` instance which contains the offset (use `Matrix4#translate` for example).

However, this is probably just making it more complex than it needs to be. You could say that the real question is why you want offset the center of model compared to the body? For example, in you second image the center of the model appears to be same as the in the first image. You only moved the `Node`, basically indicating that you want to provide an initial value for the `ModelInstance#transform` member. You can achieve this by instantiating the `ModelInstance` as follows:

```
modelInstance = new ModelInstance(model, "coneNode", true);
```

Replace `"coneNode"` with the name of the node as created it in your modeling application. The last (`true`) argument tells the ModelInstance to set its `transform` member to the transformation you've given it in the modeling application. If needed, you can call `modelInstance.transform.translate(x, y, z);` or `modelInstance.transform.trn(x, y, z);` to move the modelInstance *relative* to this transformation.

A more in-depth explanation of this can be found here: http://blog.xoppa.com/loading-a-scene-with-libgdx/

Note that this only works if you're using `.g3db` or `.g3dj`  files (e.g. using `fbx-conv`) created from a file format that supports node transformations (e.g. `.fbx`, but *not* `.obj`)

Comment: I am been reading your tutorial for 2 days now, searching the entire web to figure out what went wrong, until I found this. Wow this solves everything for me. Tnx a lot!